# SeekBar and TextView stop updating randomly

Tags: java, android, handler, android-mediaplayer, runnable

I am new to Android programming, so it is possible I am making a simple mistake.  I have implemented a MediaPlayer with a corresponding SeekBar and TextView (a countdown).  About half the time, the SeekBar and TextView stop updating during playback.  The audio files I am playing are short with a maximum time of 60 seconds....and in this particular case my files are 10-15 seconds long.

The corresponding update functions is as follows:

```
    private static MediaPlayer             mMediaPlayer;
    private static SeekBar                 mSeekBar;
    private static TextView                mClock;
    private static Handler                 mHandler = new Handler();
    .
    .
    .
    private void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            final String s = OyoUtils.constructMinSec(mMediaPlayer.getDuration() - mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            Log.e("",s + " " + mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            mSeekBar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            mClock.setText(s);

            Runnable update = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            mHandler.postDelayed(update, 200);
        } else {
            Log.e("","Not playing");
        }
    }
```

The Logs do confirm that the value of `s` and `mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` are what they should be, and continue updating with new and correct values even after the SeekBar and TextView stop updating.  An example of the Log looks like this: `0:11 4650`

The SeekBar and TextView always stop updating together, it has never been the case that one continues to update while the other fails to update.

If I pause playback after the SeekBar and TextView stop updating, and then begin playback, the SeekBar and TextView jump to correct positions/values.

There are no errors in LogCat when these values stop updating.  There is no where else in my code where I am opening a new thread, resuing mHandler, or using any Runnables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if startPlayProgressUpdater() is not running on the UI thread. Try to initialize your mHandler like this:

> private static Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

This way everything made inside the run() of the Runnable will run on the UI Thread. You could also use the views as handlers, and the Runnable would also run on the UI Thread.